# AWS Lambda http headers are coming in the response body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am developing a Rest API with AWS API Gatway(**Non proxy**) and Lambda. I want to add some headers and change response status code inside lambda.

After lot of googling everyone seems to suggest the following way to achieve this inside lambda.

```
module.exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

    const response = {
      statusCode: 201,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ "message": "Hello World!" })
    };

    callback(null, response);
};
```

But the headers and status body is coming in the response body and headers and status code seems to not change. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you follow section "Configure your API's integration point and body mapping template" on the tutorial at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda/

Comment: But this link is on how to use request headers inside lambda right?

Comment: How did you setup your integrations exactly?

Comment: It's non proxy API in API Gateway side. Attached this lambda to the resource. I think I did nothing much important apart from these. (Tried the same lambda with proxy and it's working fine)

Comment: 1. you don't need callback, api gateway calls lambda in sync. mode. You need callback in something like cloudformation template and other places where you have async call to lambda. Just return that from lambda. 2. check your api gateway config and enable info logs on it to see everything what happens inside the api gateway. There are mapping and filtering inside api gateway, you can see all of that if info logs enabled.